# How do I permanently reset the time zone in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian-squeeze, time-zone

Dreamhost seems to think that we like PDT, despite being in the Midwest. How do I change the timezone?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

A tool I found to be easier to use is `dpkg-reconfigure`. Use:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

You will be given a multitude of choices, including some that are not included in `tzselect`.

Comment: A benefit of doing it this way is that you are doing it in a reproduceable way and limit the chances for doing something wrong like putting in a timezone that does not exist.

Comment: This is good stuff, but if you need a non-interactive (and therefore scriptable) option, see my answer below.

Answer (score 15):

This is presumably a bit late for the OP, and more intended for other searchers who arrive here.

If you need a non-interactive solution, try this solution from [changing timezone with dpkg-reconfigure tzdata and debconf-set-selections](https://superuser.com/questions/498330/changing-timezone-with-dpkg-reconfigure-tzdata-and-debconf-set-selections/507354#507354)

```
echo "Europe/Zurich" > /etc/timezone 
dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

You can figure out your timezone by poking around in /usr/share/zoneinfo.  In fact the dpkg-reconfigure command above copies the appropriate file from there to /etc/localtime.  I used to just do that manually, and it seems to work fine.

Don't be too surprised if long running processes don't pick up the change.  eg Apache log timestamps come to mind.  Consider whether that matters, and hence whether you need to restart running processes or even reboot.

Comment: Beware that for this to work, it's a requirement that `/etc/localtime` does not already exist. If it exists and is a softlink to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/whatever`, it's taken as base and it is `/etc/localtime` that is updated accordingly, overwriting your changes.

Answer (score 13):

To edit it non interactively on recent Debian and Ubuntu versions (Stretch/Xenial etc.), you need to remove `/etc/localtime` as well, otherwise `/etc/timezone` will be overwritten.

```
echo 'Europe/Zurich' > /etc/timezone 
rm /etc/localtime
dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

This answer is based on mc0e' answer. I can not add a comment with my reputation.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

```
echo "TZ=Etc/UTC" >> /etc/environment
tzconfig
```

where `Etc/UTC` is your preferred timezone you found using `tzselect`.

**Longer version**

When you're using

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

the timezone information is not kept after reboot. You can verify your settings with

```
diff -s /etc/localtime /usr/share/zoneinfo/`cat /etc/timezone`
```

If you're only updating `/etc/timezone`, the update won't be consistent with `/etc/localtime`, thus [it's better to execute](https://wiki.debian.org/TimeZoneChanges)

```
tzconfig
```

Use `tzselect` to find out which time zones actually exists (or simply browse `/usr/share/zoneinfo` directory).

In POSIX systems the `TZ` should take precedence before `/etc/localtime`:

```
export TZ='Europe/Berlin'
$ date
Tue Apr 10 08:51:03 CEST 2018
export TZ='Pacific/Efate'
$ date
Tue Apr 10 18:28:33 +11 2018
```

Using directly `TZ` [can save you many system calls](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/02/21/set-environment-variable-save-thousands-of-system-calls/) as frequently used date/time related functions has to access filesystem each time some program asks for current date. It's a micro-optimization, but quite simple one.

Comment: Are you positive exporting `TZ` in your profile file creates a symlink? That does not sound true at all in my experience. Perhaps you meant "Also make sure to create the symlink..."?

Comment: @amn No, that won't create a symlink, I've tried to clarify that. But `$TZ` variable is read by `glibc` functions: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html

Comment: shouldn't it be `echo "TZ=Etc/UTC" >> /etc/environment` ? you're missing `TZ=` part... (if case someone is still running  ancient debian versions). Also, noninteractive stuff like daemons would still use `/etc/localtime` version instead of one set in `TZ`...

Comment: @MatijaNalis Yes, you're right. Thanks for correction!